# SQL statement is giving me the following error message Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Background**

I am a bit new to the whole JOIN concept of SQL and trying to write a SQL statement which will get a country's name based on President ID which is in another table, that later points at another table that contains the country's name.

**Tables**

**[President]**

```
ID | PresidentID | Name | Population Governed
1    3             ME     1,000,000,000
```

**[CountryPopulation]**

```
ID |PresidentID| Population Number| CountryID
1   3             1,000,000,000      12
```

**[CountryName]**

```
ID | CountryID | CountryName
3    12            USA
```

**Problem**: I have written a SQL statement where I am trying to to get the country's name based on the president ID, however my statement is showing an error:

> Ambiguous column name 'PresdientID'.

SQL statement

```
SELECT
    PresidentID
FROM 
    President A 
INNER JOIN 
    CountryPopulation B ON A.PresdientID = B.PresdientID 
WHERE 
    B.CountryID IN (SELECT CountryName 
                    FROM CountryName 
                    WHERE CountryID = B.CountryID)
```

Comment: You need an alias for `PresdientID` in your `SELECT`, since it's in both tables, it's *ambiguous* which table you are selecting it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you've selected, `PresidentID` is ambiguous.You need to specify which table you want to supply the value for `PresidentID`, like this:

```
Select
  A.PresdientID
  From President A INNER JOIN 
  CountryPopulation B ON A.PresdientID = B.PresdientID 
  WHERE B.CountryID IN (SELECT CountryName FROM CountryName WHERE CountryID = B.CountryID)
```

**EDIT**

Your question states that you're trying to get the `CountryName` based on the `PresidientID` value.

If you know the `PresidientID` value, I would think you'd simply do this:

```
DECLARE @PresidientID INT = 3
SELECT cn.CountryName
    FROM CountryName cn JOIN CountryPopulation cp ON cn.CountryID = cp.CountryID
    WHERE cp.PresidientID = @PresidientID;
```

That said, it looks like your database design may be incorrect.  It seems that there are quite a few "ID" fields sprinkled around.  For instance, your `President` table contains both an `ID` field and a `PresidientID` field; also your `CountryName` table contains both an `ID` field and a `CountryID` field.  Also, you have the same information in multiple tables (population number, population governed).

Would it not be better to put all of the country attributes into a single table named `Country`?  Consider this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Country](
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [Population] INT,
    [PresidentID] INT  -- Foreign Key to president
)

CREATE TABLE [President](
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PresidentName] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, however I am now getting the following error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'USA' to data type int.  Is my Statement constructed correctly ?

Comment: I don't see how/where the country name is being manipulated in the query I've show in the result.  What was the exact query you executed that caused the error?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is unsure whether you want to return A.PresidentID or B.PresidentID. You need to specify even though the values would be the same in this case.